# Salesforce Auth provider issue for experience users

Tags: salesforce, single-sign-on, amazon-cognito, apex

i am trying to set AWS Cognito as Auth provider to log in salesforce.
I have set up an "Auth Provider" (called it Cognito) enabled it as login option both for salesforce login and for community (in community workspace).

[Auth provider settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oRpvm.png)

When i try to login to salesforce using Cognito credentials i manage to do it without issues, but when i click on "Cognito" as a login option in my community i get an error even before i try to enter my credentials:

[Trying to log in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2BGv8.png)

[Error and url string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZiZLD.png)

I use different credentials for user that is internal and user that is external, although in case of community login i did not even manage to enter my creds. In url string i see that error is "redirect_mismatch" but i am not sure what that means in current context and how to resolve it. In my Registration helper i have only adjusted "createUser" method to return a user that i already have in my org:

```
global User createUser(Id portalId, Auth.UserData data){    
    return [SELECT Id, Name, ContactId FROM User WHERE FederationIdentifier = :data.email];
}
```

If someone has experience with using Cognito as auth provider for salesforce communities i will be glad for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Redirect mismatch is referring to your callback URL being different than the one you defined in your user pool settings. Go to user pool settings and click on app client settings. Here you will see fields for sign in and sign out urls. Put in the correct callback/redirect url here. You can enter multiple urls separated by commas.